# CSS Drop Shadow effect not displaying correctly in safari

Tags: html, css, svg, safari

I found strange behaviour i can't understand for safari browser Version 16.1 (18614.2.9.1.12).
This is my html:

```
<div class="top-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="drop-shadow-1">
            <img src="logo.svg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is css style:

```
.drop-shadow-1 {
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 0px 125px) drop-shadow(20px 0px 28px #D42CCA);
}
```

and my svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="800.000000pt" height="800.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 800.000000 800.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,800.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="white" stroke="none">
<path d="..."/>
</g>
</svg>
```

when i change third parameter of second drop-shadow from 28 to 29 or higher my svg becomes invisible. the real value i need is 200, but i found that issue happens on transition between 28 and 29.
Is there any reason of this behaviour?